# Is there a way to get the details of a class in a typescipt program so that I can pass these details to a logger(winston)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, winston

I have written a wrapper over winston.In order to test this I have also written a "Greeting class" wherein I make a call to logger.info().I want my log to also display the class name.
For this when I invoke logger.info() I also have to pass the name of the class so that my wrapper knows which class the logger was invoked at.But the problem is that I do not want the programmer to specify that.I want to create a level of abstraction.My wrapper should be user friendly.
Is there a way to do this?
If the above mentioned problem is not solvable is there a way to get all details of a class and its methods.I tried passing "this" but im getting something like {greeting:world} 
Sorry if im not using correct terminology.I am new to javascript and node.js.

wrapper:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { injectable } from "inversify";
import { createLogger, format, transports, Logger as Iwinston } from "winston";

const { combine, timestamp, metadata, json, errors, label, printf } = format;

@injectable()
export default class Logger {
  public logger: Iwinston;

  private selfInfo: string;

  constructor() {
    this.selfInfo = "winston version >= 3.x";
    this.logger = createLogger(this.readOptions());
    this.addTransportConsole(this.getTransportConsoleOptions());
  }

  public info(message: string, data?: any): void {
    console.log(data);
    this.logger.info(message,data);
  }

  public error(message: string, data?: any): void {
    this.logger.error(message, data);
  }

  public getCoreVersion(): string {
    return this.selfInfo;
  }

  private readOptions(): Object {
    return {
      format: combine(
        label({ label: process.env.APP_NAME || "Unknown App" }),
        errors({ stack: true }),
        timestamp(),
        json(),
      ),
      transports:[
        new transports.File({filename:'error.log',level:'info'})
      ]
    };
  }

  private getTransportConsoleOptions(): transports.ConsoleTransportOptions {
    return {
      debugStdout: false
    };
  }

  private addTransportConsole(
    options?: transports.ConsoleTransportOptions
  ): void {
    this.logger.add(new transports.Console(options));
  }
}
```

My test:

```
import Logger from '../lib/component/logger/appLogger/winstonLogger'
let logger:Logger
logger = new Logger()

test('Winston Logger Test',() => {
class Greeter {
  greeting: string;
  constructor(message: string) {
      this.greeting = message;
      logger.info('hello',this)
  }
  greet() {
    console.log(globalThis.Document)
      logger.info('in greet')
      return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
  }
}
let greeter = new Greeter("world");
greeter.greet()
})

//{"level":"info","message":"hello","metadata":{},"label":"Unknown App","timestamp":"2019-11-22T09:30:07.256Z"}
```

Answer (score 1):

So what i would do here is make them pass the class as a parameter when you create the instance of the logger:

```
const logger = new Logger<Greeter>(Greeter)

test('Winston Logger Test',() => {
class Greeter {
....
```

This then means this logger instance is linked to this class now for the whole time it is used. In your logger class you can then in the constructor set the name of that class which i have abstracted away in `nameByInstance` method.

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { injectable } from "inversify";
import { createLogger, format, transports, Logger as Iwinston } from "winston";

const { combine, timestamp, metadata, json, errors, label, printf } = format;

@injectable()
export default class Logger<TInstance> {
  public logger: Iwinston;

  private selfInfo: string;

  private loggerInstanceName: string;

  constructor(instance: TInstance) {
    this.selfInfo = "winston version >= 3.x";
    this.logger = createLogger(this.readOptions());
    this.addTransportConsole(this.getTransportConsoleOptions());
    this.loggerInstanceName = this.nameByInstance(instance);

    console.log(this.loggerInstanceName) // Greeter :)
  }

  public info(message: string, data?: any): void {
    console.log(data);
    this.logger.info(message,data);
  }

  public error(message: string, data?: any): void {
    this.logger.error(message, data);
  }

  public getCoreVersion(): string {
    return this.selfInfo;
  }

  private readOptions(): Object {
    return {
      format: combine(
        label({ label: process.env.APP_NAME || "Unknown App" }),
        errors({ stack: true }),
        timestamp(),
        json(),
      ),
      transports:[
        new transports.File({filename:'error.log',level:'info'})
      ]
    };
  }

  private getTransportConsoleOptions(): transports.ConsoleTransportOptions {
    return {
      debugStdout: false
    };
  }

  private addTransportConsole(
    options?: transports.ConsoleTransportOptions
  ): void {
    this.logger.add(new transports.Console(options));
  }

  private nameByInstance(type: TInstance): string {
    return type.prototype["constructor"]["name"];
  }
}
```

This now means you can just let them do `logger.info('hello')` and you have context to the class name in the logger instance `loggerInstanceName` to add that to the message they have passed in within the `info` method in `logger` without them having to do it.. nice hey?!